# Detect grabbed file systemwide with coordinates and path to file

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa

Can i detect the coordinates and pathinfo of a file / files, when the user starts to move a file somewhere?
(Pressing and holding left-mouse on file)

Objective-C or Swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This info may be found in `NSDragPboard` pasteboard. The filenames are usually located in `NSFilenamesPboardType`. Take a look at Apple's [ClipboardViewer sources](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ClipboardViewer/Introduction/Intro.html), it might be useful for you.

Comment: I found good stuff its working global, but not on the desktop!
Prints the coordinates in of dragging file in screen, but also all other events, like window dragging.. have to check the type.

    NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(NSEventMask.LeftMouseDraggedMask, handler: { (event: NSEvent!) -> Void in
            println("Dragged \(event.locationInWindow.x)x\(event.locationInWindow.y)");
    })

Comment: I wouldn't rely on global event monitor in this case, because it may be disabled by user. But you can use both of ways: detect drag start and then read NSDragPboard contents. Lazy pasteboard content polling will be fine too, but less energy-efficient.